# Realization of fake infinite list

Tags: list-manipulation

I would like to define an "infinite list" `list` in the following sense: first, we set a finite number of elements `list[[k_i]]` (with $k_i$'s not necessarily successive) of `list` to particular values. When refering to the $k$th element `list[[k]]` (where $k$ can be infinitely large)  it should give either the fixed value if it was defined, or else `0`. Is there a way to realize this kind of fake infinite list in *Mathematica*?

Comment: Abstractly, a list is just a function `L` that returns an element on an input `k`, where `k` is a positive integer.  So you could program it with a function.  You could even overload `Part`: `L /: Part[L, k_] := L[k]`.  It won't be a `List` though, and listable functions won't thread over the values, etc.

Comment: Perhaps https://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/1467915 provides this. If you search mathematica.stackexchange for lazy lists you will find a few dozen questions and answers dealing with this.

Comment: If you can make do with 2^31 elements instead of Infinity, then [SparseArray](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/SparseArray.html) might be useful.